# Firebase Android Listview - Error when reading multiple items on a ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found this when saving multiple data on my app.

[In my database I am saving multiple workouts under the "date" node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74MAp.png)

When I read them on a list, there is an error which makes it read the "workoutName" and "workoutCategory" incorrectly.

[This is the way it being read on the listview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWQdB.png) Both the name and category is being shown incorrectly, and if I add more there will be more of the same errors.

Here is the code I am using to read the data from firebase.

```html
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String readDate = theDate.getText().toString();

        DatabaseReference WorkoutDB = currentUserDB.child(currentUId).child("workouts");
        DatabaseReference currentDate = WorkoutDB.child(readDate);

      
        currentDate.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                workoutList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot workoutSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   // WorkoutDB viewworkout = workoutSnapshot.getValue(com.example.mohan.finalyear.WorkoutDB.class);
                    WorkoutDB viewworkout = workoutSnapshot.getValue(WorkoutDB.class);
                    workoutList.add(viewworkout);
                }
    
                listViewWorkouts.setAdapter(workoutadapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              
            }
        });


 }
```

Comment: You say that are "being shown incorrectly". What is the correct way in which you want to be shown.

Comment: I think the problem is with the ListView itself. If there's a lot of data being read, you have to drag/scroll down the list view. lets say 5 records will fill up the screen and if you have more that. When you scroll down, the listview will refresh again. Showing the first 5 record again